Spring Data JPA/Hibernate: Proper way to map Query with specific fields and joins into a Nested DTO
I have the following 3 entities:-
Parent.java:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Parent {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long parentId;
    
    private String field;
    
    private String fieldNotInProjection;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> children;

}

Child.java:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Child {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long childId;
    
    private String field;
    
    private String fieldNotInProjection;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "father")
    private List<GrandChild> grandChildren;
    
}

GrandChild.java:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class GrandChild {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long grandChildId;
    
    private String field;
    
    private String fieldNotInProjection;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "father_id")
    private Child father;

}

Relationships between them is as follows:
Parent--1-N-<Child--1-N-<GrandChild
I want my results to be projected in the following dto class:-
JoinedDto.java:
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
class JoinedDto {

    private String parentField;
    private List<ChildWithGrandChildDto> childrenAndGrandChildren;
    
}

ChildWithGrandChildDto.java: (used inside above dto)
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
class ChildWithGrandChildDto {

    private String childField;
    private List<String> grandChildFields;

}

I want hibernate to keep using a single specific minimal query with only the required field and joins like the following:-
select
    p1_0.parent_id,
    p1_0.field,
    c1_0.child_id,
    c1_0.field,
    gc1_0.field 
from
    parent p1_0 
left join
    child c1_0 
        on p1_0.parent_id=c1_0.parent_id 
left join
    grand_child gc1_0 
        on c1_0.child_id=gc1_0.father_id

in the above query we can see the field field_not_in_projection of the tables are not returned, as we do not want to use them in our dto.
in the dto parent_id and child_id are not there but I am returning them in above query to use them in my mapping methods below. But they are redundant for actual data that needs to be sent as dto and if possible, should not be included in the above query.
I am using the below code to achieve it right now:-
in my repository I am using interface based projection to get the list of raw rows, that are retuned using the join query
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p.parentId as parentId,"
            + " p.field AS parentField,"
            + " c.childId AS childId,"
            + " c.field AS childField,"
            + " gc.field AS grandChildField"
            + " FROM Parent p"
            + " LEFT JOIN p.children c"
            + " LEFT JOIN c.grandChildren gc")
    List<JoinedRow> findAllJoinedRows();
    
    interface JoinedRow {
        
        Long getParentId();
        String getParentField();
        Long getChildId();
        String getChildField();
        String getGrandChildField();
        
    }
    
}

Example Returned Data inside List<JoinedRow> :

now I am using the following custom helper methods, to manually map these raw rows into my dto JoinedDto(mentioned at start) :-

    // converts the list of projected raw table rows interface into list of nested JoinedDto object
    private List<JoinedDto> mapToJoinedDtoStream(List<ParentRepository.JoinedRow> joinedRows) {
        return joinedRows
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ParentRepository.JoinedRow::getParentId, 
                        Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getChildId()==null? -1 : p.getChildId())))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(this::rowEntryToDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    private JoinedDto rowEntryToDto(Entry<Long, Map<Long, List<JoinedRow>>> p) {
        String parentField = p.getValue().values().iterator().next().get(0).getParentField();
        List<ChildWithGrandChildDto> childrenWithGrandChildren = p.getValue()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(q -> q.getKey() != -1)
                .map(Entry::getValue)
                .map(q -> new ChildWithGrandChildDto(q.get(0).getChildField(), q.stream()
                        .map(ParentRepository.JoinedRow::getGrandChildField)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        JoinedDto dto = new JoinedDto(parentField, childrenWithGrandChildren);
        return dto;
    }


I can use this above helper method mapToJoinedDtoStream() to map the joined raw table rows returned from repository into list of dto as follows:-
TestDbRelationshipsApplicationTests.java:
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class TestDbRelationshipsApplicationTests {
    
    @Autowired
    private ParentRepository parentRepository;
    
    @Test
    void joinTest() {
        List<ParentRepository.JoinedRow> l = parentRepository.findAllJoinedRows();
        List<JoinedDto> dtos = mapToJoinedDtoStream(l);
        System.out.println(dtos);
    }
}

Is there any way to omit these helper methods required to convert the rows into dto, and instead use jpa/hibernate directly to map the data returned from that minimalistic joined query, directly into my dto? just like the way, it maps into entity objects, I want it to map it to my custom dto object, keeping the query minimalistic as specified above.
Thank you.
My PostgreSQL Table Scripts:
CREATE TABLE parent (
    parent_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    field VARCHAR(255),
    field_not_in_projection VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
    child_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    field VARCHAR(255),
    field_not_in_projection VARCHAR(255),
    parent_id BIGINT REFERENCES parent(parent_id)
);

CREATE TABLE grand_child (
    grand_child_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    field VARCHAR(255),
    field_not_in_projection VARCHAR(255),
    father_id BIGINT REFERENCES child(child_id)
);

-- Insert into parent table
INSERT INTO parent (field, field_not_in_projection) VALUES
('Parent Field 1', 'Parent Not In Projection 1'),
('Parent Field 2', 'Parent Not In Projection 2'),
('Parent Field 3', 'Parent Not In Projection 3');

-- Insert into child table
INSERT INTO child (field, field_not_in_projection, parent_id) VALUES
('Child Field 1-1', 'Child Not In Projection 1-1', (SELECT parent_id FROM parent WHERE field = 'Parent Field 1')),
('Child Field 1-2', 'Child Not In Projection 1-2', (SELECT parent_id FROM parent WHERE field = 'Parent Field 1')),
('Child Field 2-1', 'Child Not In Projection 2-1', (SELECT parent_id FROM parent WHERE field = 'Parent Field 2')),
('Child Field 3-1', 'Child Not In Projection 3-1', (SELECT parent_id FROM parent WHERE field = 'Parent Field 3')),
('Child Field 3-2', 'Child Not In Projection 3-2', (SELECT parent_id FROM parent WHERE field = 'Parent Field 3'));

-- Insert into grand_child table
INSERT INTO grand_child (field, field_not_in_projection, father_id) VALUES
('Grandchild Field 1-1-1', 'Grandchild Not In Projection 1-1-1', (SELECT child_id FROM child WHERE field = 'Child Field 1-1')),
('Grandchild Field 1-1-2', 'Grandchild Not In Projection 1-1-2', (SELECT child_id FROM child WHERE field = 'Child Field 1-1')),
('Grandchild Field 1-2-1', 'Grandchild Not In Projection 1-2-1', (SELECT child_id FROM child WHERE field = 'Child Field 1-2')),
('Grandchild Field 2-1-1', 'Grandchild Not In Projection 2-1-1', (SELECT child_id FROM child WHERE field = 'Child Field 2-1')),
('Grandchild Field 3-1-1', 'Grandchild Not In Projection 3-1-1', (SELECT child_id FROM child WHERE field = 'Child Field 3-1')),
('Grandchild Field 3-2-1', 'Grandchild Not In Projection 3-2-1', (SELECT child_id FROM child WHERE field = 'Child Field 3-2'));


The closest I have came across to achieving what I want is using Nested Interfaces for projection with JOIN Fetch and using SET instead of List for *ToMany Entity fields. But it does not provide exactly what I want and adds a lot of quirks.
It generates only 2 queries:-
select
    p1_0.parent_id,
    c1_0.parent_id,
    c1_0.child_id,
    c1_0.field,
    c1_0.field_not_in_projection,
    gc1_0.father_id,
    gc1_0.grand_child_id,
    gc1_0.field,
    gc1_0.field_not_in_projection,
    p1_0.field,
    p1_0.field_not_in_projection 
from
    parent p1_0 
left join
    child c1_0 
        on p1_0.parent_id=c1_0.parent_id 
left join
    grand_child gc1_0 
        on c1_0.child_id=gc1_0.father_id

select
    gc1_0.father_id,
    gc1_0.grand_child_id,
    gc1_0.field,
    gc1_0.field_not_in_projection 
from
    grand_child gc1_0 
where
    gc1_0.father_id=?

but we can see it selects unwanted fields (field_not_in_projection etc.)
I am using the following method in the repository to achieve it:-
    @Query("SELECT p"
            + " FROM Parent p"
            + " LEFT JOIN FETCH p.children c"
            + " LEFT JOIN FETCH c.grandChildren")
    List<JoinedDtoNew> findAllProjectedByNew();

It returns a list of the following ProjectionInterface:-
interface JoinedDtoNew {
    String getField();
    List<ChildDto> getChildren();
    
    interface ChildDto {
        String getField();
        List<GrandChildDto> getGrandChildren();
        
        interface GrandChildDto {
            String getField();
        }
    }
}

Instead of the JoinedDto, I am using this interface directly, where I don't return list of grandChildField but a separate interface GrandChildDto which wraps that field for compatibility with projection.
But it throws this exception:-
org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

To avoid this exception- I need to use Set instead of List in my entities like this:-
Parent.java:
public class Parent {
    
    // existing code...
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> children; //Changed to Set instead of List

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(children, field, fieldNotInProjection, parentId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Parent other = (Parent) obj;
        return Objects.equals(children, other.children) && Objects.equals(field, other.field)
                && Objects.equals(fieldNotInProjection, other.fieldNotInProjection)
                && Objects.equals(parentId, other.parentId);
    }
    
}

Child.java:
public class Child {
    
    // existing code...
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "father")
    private Set<GrandChild> grandChildren; // Changed to Set instread of List

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(childId, field, fieldNotInProjection, grandChildren);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Child other = (Child) obj;
        return Objects.equals(childId, other.childId) && Objects.equals(field, other.field)
                && Objects.equals(fieldNotInProjection, other.fieldNotInProjection)
                && Objects.equals(grandChildren, other.grandChildren);
    }
    
}

However, it is not the best solution to avoid this exception as Vlad Mihalcea Mentions it in his answer as the worst solution...
But maybe he meant only for joins from same table with multiple table and not from same table with another table and then from that other table with one more table, as probably this does not give raise to the cartesian product problem.
But, it is also not specific to this particular query but modifies the Entity, probably affecting all the queries related to it. I looked at the other solutions in the question but they seem to be deprecated / generate more queries.
Due to all these quirks I cannot mark it as answer, but I am posting it in case someone can improve upon it and provide the actual solution or if in case it can be helpful to someone.
